# travis.ci keeps on failing when running "bundle exec rake"

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, travis-ci

I am trying to get automated testing sorted out with Travis.ci. However, at the moment the build keeps on failing when trying to execute `bundle exec rake`.
This is what I see...

```
$ bundle exec rake
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'default'
/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

The command "bundle exec rake" exited with 1.

Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

My unit tests are in the test folder in the main directory and is named test_np_search.rb. I understand that I am somehow supposed to point travis to this location in order to run the unit tests but I have no idea how to do this.

I have read the ruby related documentation on travis.ci a number of times and have looked online for tutorials, however I have been unable to get this to work.

The whole github repository in question is here: https://github.com/IsmailM/NeuroPeptideSearch

The Travis.CI link is here: https://travis-ci.org/IsmailM/NeuroPeptideSearch

I have been trying to get this sorted for over a week now with any success and so would be highly grateful if anyone could help me.

Many Thank

Comment: Ismail, did you add `require 'bundler/gem_tasks"` in your `Rakefile`? I normally just have `require 'bundler'` there. Try changing that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if you want to execute `bundle exec rake` on travis, you will have to make sure, that it runs on your local machine!

if you call `rake` without providing a task-name, it will assume that you want to run the default-task.

if you want to run your minitest testsuite as a default-task, you have to do this:

```
require "rake/testtask"

Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  t.pattern = "test/**/*_test.rb"
end

task default: :test
```